# Check if Windows Server 2008R2 can use TLS 1.2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, ssl

as SalesForce drops TLS 1.0 next week, we are forced to use TLS 1.1 or 1.2 in our API calls, which we use to extract data for our DWH from Windows Server 2008R2 using SSIS custom CozyRoc components. We installed the patches and made sure that the registry has required entries as it is stated in [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1.1-and-tls-1.2-as-a-default-secure-protocols-in) article. We added no keys to SCHANNEL though, now the only protocol listed there is SSL 2.0.

Next, after rebooting of course, I recorded a trace with Wireshark to find out that our CozyRoc components in SSIS packages use TLS 1.0, as in Server Hello message we are getting TLS 1.0 in the handshake protocol section. The CozyRoc components which construct the call support TLS 1.2.

My question is: how can I test if our server can use TLS 1.2 to communicate with SalesForce? I know that disabling TLS 1.0 can possibly mess up other connections, so I do not want to do that. Ideally, I would like to know that my SSIS packages use TLS 1.2.

UPDATE: I tried to connect to our test Salesforce site, at which TLS 1.0 is disabled. Now when trying to connect I receive an error saying

> "UNSUPPORTED_CLIENT: TLS 1.0 has been disabled in this organization.
>   Please use TLS 1.1 or higher when connecting to Salesforce using
>   https. (System.Web.Services)"|

I still do not know if the one to blame is my server setup or the CozyRoc component, so I am now looking for any way to ensure that TLS 1.2 works on the server, independently of the SSIS setup. Any ideas?

Comment: I found a nice SalesForce [setting](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=TLS-1-0-Disablement-Critical-Update-Console-CRUC-Setting&language=en_US&type=1) to help me disable TLS 1.0 on the SalesForce side.

Comment: In your case, I would post the question directly to Salesforce support https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000214850&type=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to my question is awfully simple, it is enough to visit https://www.howsmyssl.com/. Also, Wireshark trace indicates that my server uses TLS 1.2 to exchange handshakes with the Salesforce site while testing the connection.

Bottleneck in my case is the Cozyroc SSIS+ version - currently it is 1.6.103 and you need at least 1.6.104 to use TLS 1.1 or higher, so make sure to check that.

Comment: What browser? Firefox and Chrome use their own stacks and can do TLS1.2 (and other new features like stapling and http2) even when apps using schannel can't. Only IE (or Edge) gives you a read on schannel.

Comment: Thanks for your point, I used IE. Ran into a problem on my production server because it does not allow any outbound connections through IE but I was still able to track requests with Wireshark.

Answer (score 7):

Please keep noted that TLS 1.2 is disabled per default in Windows 2008 (see [here](https://blogs.microsoft.com/microsoftsecure/2017/07/20/tls-1-2-support-added-to-windows-server-2008/)). So you need to enable it per registry change (see below), you also need to understand that there is a client config and a server config. So if you for example enable TLS 1.2 on a client level but not on a server level an nMAP against port 443 will not show that TLS 1.2 is enabled as its only enabled for a client.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
```

What you need here hardly depends on your application and how it interacts with a remote service. So for example if the 3rd party application will use a https session towards your environment then this would be a server side configuration. However if you have a 3rd party plugin running as a service which perform connections against the 3rd party server then this is a client configuration.

Additionally there is a hotfix which allows applications and services that are written by using WinHTTP for Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) connections to use TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2 protocols which you should install (it not already done as this is a older fix; see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-a-default-secure-protocols-in)).

Additionally if the 3rd party component didn´t make use from the Microsoft SCHANNEL implementation any changes on the registry side will not work. Because it could be that the 3rd party component are using another SSL implementation like OpenSSL. In that case you need to get in contact with the vendor to check how you can enable TLS 1.2 here. This for example is also true when using Java components (e.g. TomCat). Then adjusting the  Microsoft SCHANNEL implementation will not affect them.

*SalesForce itself has a very good documentation from the above in much more details then I could give here. So you should check that out as well (see [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000221207&type=1)). Additional they offer multiple "how to test" way to test the TLS configuration which you can then perform.*

Comment: In addition to the Schannel registry keys you may need .NET updates and .NET registry keys depending on what applications needed. More info here: https://github.com/TheLevelUp/pos-tls-patcher

Answer (score 0):

**Steps:** Checked on Windows server 2010 as well

- **Step 1:** open command prompt and type "regedit" without the quote
- **Step 2:** If prompted for administrator permission please allow for it saying yes.
- **Step 3:** Browse through the path I showed in the image here -->

[image: Browse the Path for TLS check]

If it's enabled it will show you as enabled as showed in the pic. I hope you understood by now or else leave a comment here